# How can I get the (static) class name for a Flex object?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Consider

```
var s: String = null;
```

Is there a function which takes an object such as `s` and yields the static type name (the one used when declaring the object), `String` in this case?

I've been using [`getQualifiedClassName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName%28%29) so far but just noticed that it doesn't work with `null` values - I wonder whether there's anything like that which doesn't try to determine the dynamic type but rather the "static" type (in case Flex makes this distinction...).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get "static" type once you compile your project, because every type at runtime is dynamic, and coercion is widely used to determine which type is this object. Null objects are just that, you cannot get anything out of a null value. So, either assign a kind of default value for such objects you need to be checked for type at runtime, or store a proper type (a variable of type Class) alongside such an object.